# Windows Server 2008 Software RAID between versions of Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, software-raid

I'm considering moving my x86 based Server 2008 install to x64, and I just wanted to know if moving a mirrored (Software RAID 1) array into the new install will be a hassle? I have the data off on an external drive just in case, and I read another question on this site that said moving it between installs is OK, but I wanted to see if it would work between architectures (x86 and x64)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this RAID-1 your system drive? If it is, then what Sam said is correct, because you can't do an in-place x86 to x64 upgrade, and even if you could, dynamic disks are not supported for installations.

However if your RAID-1 is NOT your system disk, then after you've re-installed Windows it will ask you to re-import the dynamic disks. Once this is done, the volumes should re-appear as they did in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can't upgrade from x86 to x64, you have to do a fresh install. So assuming your software RAID is provided by Windows, then when you re-install you will lose that, so you will need to use your backup to restore your data to your recreated RAID array once you're done.

Comment: Windows will re-import dynamic disks from other installations of Windows. Done it plenty of times.